# parse XML attribute via PHP XMLReader

Tags: php, xml

the followings are XML sample code.

```
<m:ad xmlns:m="http://www.w3c.org/soap">
    <title><![CDATA[TITLE]]></title>
    <phone>123456789</phone>
    <attributeGroup>
       <attribute id="14" name="A1">40</attribute>
       <attribute id="15" name="A2">50</attribute>
   </attributeGroup>
</m:ad>
```

I only know PHP XMLReader to get value

```
$reader = new XMLReader();        
if ($reader->name == "title" && $reader->nodeType ==XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
    echo $reader2->read(); // will get TITLE   
 }
```

But how to get attribute A1, A2 . I would like to get 40, and 50 both .

Answer (score 5):

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->xml('<m:ad xmlns:m="http://www.w3c.org/soap">
    <title><![CDATA[TITLE]]></title>
    <phone>123456789</phone>
    <attributeGroup>
       <attribute id="14" name="A1">40</attribute>
       <attribute id="15" name="A2">50</attribute>
   </attributeGroup>
</m:ad>');


while ( $reader->read() ) {
  if (  $reader->nodeType ==XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == "attribute" ) {
    printf("id=%s, name=%s\n", $reader->getAttribute('id'), $reader->getAttribute('name'));
  }
}
```

prints

```
id=14, name=A1
id=15, name=A2
```

Comment: +1, but what if I don't know what attributes will be supplied?

Comment: SDC: That question is a little bit too broad for me to answer. What are you trying to achieve? Could be that schemas are what you're looking for, or something like odata, may even be that transforming via XSL(t) is the answer ....or something completely different ;-)

Comment: I ended up using `$reader->attributeCount` and then a using `for()` loop to read each attribute in turn using `$reader->moveToAttributeNo()`. That allows me to access all attributes, without having to know in advance what they will be.